# Special characters in libgdx's textfield do not work

Tags: java, macos, libgdx, special-characters, textfield

I can use setText("åäö") but if I type on my keyboard it doesn't show up, this doesn't work either

```
            public void keyTyped(TextField textField, char key) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), key);
            }
```

The strange thing is that it doesn't work on mac but it does work on Windows, does anyone have an answer for that? 
Thank You!

Here's another question with a similarly topic!

**How do you get input from special characters in Libgdx?**

I have tried to get the ascii value and puting it through

```
Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(ascii value);
```

but it doesn't work. I have set my project encoding to UTF-8 and I can print special characters like åäö.

Edit:
I tried this

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputProcessor() {

        @Override
        public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
            System.out.println(character);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Didn't print åäö

Comment: Encode the String might help. Use UTF8

Comment: @BennX It doesn't work, because key is not å, ä or ö. key is nothing if you know what I mean, but do you have any idea why it works on Windows and not on Os x?

Comment: Do both things work on Windows and not on Mac? Can you type åäö in other Applications when you are using a Mac?

Comment: Yes, I can type åäö in other Applications,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**

It seems, that this is related to a bug with unicode characters in lwjgl on OSX:
[[FIXED] Unicode input](http://lwjgl.org/forum/index.php?topic=4074.0)

If you update to the latest lwjgl library 2.9.1 this should be fixed. From the changelog:

> 2013-10-13  kappaOne
>
> - .../org/lwjgl/opengl/MacOSXNativeKeyboard.java,
>     src/native/macosx/org_lwjgl_opengl_Display.m: Fix keyboard key
>     codes to return Unicode characters instead of ASCII characters

see: [2.9.1-changelog.txt](http://www.lwjgl.org/changelogs/2.9.1-changelog.txt)

---

**Original Answer**

> How do you get input from special characters in Libgdx?

You can implement the interface com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor and set the current input processor by calling `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputProcessor );`

Then you should be able to receive notifications about all typed characters (special or not) in the method  InputProcessor#keyTyped(char c).

Actually this is more or less, what the class TextField does (not exactly, it listens for input by extending com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener).

I had a quick look at the relevant source code of TextFields keyTyped method:

```
[...]
if (font.containsCharacter(character)) {
   // here the character gets added to the text field
}
[...]
```

So it seems, that the font of the text field must support the character, otherwise it will not be displayed. I have no mac to test this, but I would guess, that the BitmapFont used by default on your mac does not support the special characters. Try to set a different BitmapFont for the TextField (see TextField.setStyle(TextFieldStyle style)) and see if this solves the problem.

Comment: What happens during the keyTyped method in your InputProcessor when you type åäö? Isn't it even being invoked or does it print wrong characters?

Comment: Just edited my answer: This is most likely fixed in lwjgl 2.9.1

Comment: Thanks for everything, haven't tried it yet but i'm sure this is the answer, thanks!

Comment: @thetheodor Great, that it worked. Would you perhaps consider accepting this answer then? - I believe you have forgotten